# Which DAW handles time modulation (groove) best?

Tags: daw, tempo, time-management

I am searching for a sequencer with good handling of tempo Modulation. Looping tempo mod Clips would be good. Precise bpm values I miss so far at the DAWs I know

excuse language.

Comment: By good handling, do you mean best quality, or easiest to use?

Comment: Which DAWs have you tried so far specifically?

Answer (score 2):

Pro Tools has some of the best time-stretching algorithms. Check out Elastic Audio.

Comment: I think it depends on exactly what one is looking for. For speeding up or slowing down audio, Pro Tools has probably the best sound quality. For actual work flows of changing the timing of musical events without so much regard to sound quality, Ableton Live's warping features are very impressive.

Answer (score 0):

the new FL (version 12.3+) supports real time audio stretching and resampling with quite a high quality, I suggest looking into that